# Overlay an UIImage above an UIImageView, possible? example code?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, overlay

Is it possible to set an image over an other image, 
respectively to overlay an image above an UIImage.

I give some code:

- Headerfile:

  ```
  @property (nonatomic,assign)UIImageView* imageView;
  ```
- Implementationfile

  ```
  UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lamp.png"];
  ```

---

The "imageView.image" has got an image and above that I will have this lamp, but later on it has to be possible to move it.

I searched some methods, but all methods gave me warnings.

Could you help me how to manage it? And is Core Animation an alternative to handle that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add it as a subview. `UIImageView` is a `UIView` like any other.

```
UIImage *overlayImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"lamp.png"];
UIImageView *overlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:overlayImage];
[self.imageView addSubview:overlayImageView];
```

Comment: Many thanks for this quick answer.I copied your code into my code, there is no warning, but also no reaction. The output of the NSLog shows that the compiler was in my method. In Addition I have already a background image. Is there anything to add, for example a method called removeFromSuperview: ? or is it an issue of lucency?

Comment: Trying checking to make sure the `overlayImageView` you created is actually working. Is `overlayImage` not null?

Comment: woow thanks. the overlayImageView was null...and after the change everything works. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use another `UIImageView`. A `UIImage` doesn't refer to an actual view in the interface, it's used as a reference to an image to be reused in code.

```
UIImageView* lampImageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:overlayImage];
```

This way you can move it around anywhere over the first image view.

Comment: Thank you very much. Like I wrote in the comment of kubi, the photo does not appear.